# Understanding objects in a array and how the length property works on objects

Tags: javascript

Have a look at the below code:

```
var a = new Array(); // or just []
a[0] = 0
a['one'] = 1;
a['two'] = 2;
a['three'] = 3;

for (var k in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        alert('key is: ' + k + ', value is: ' + a[k]);
    }
}
alert(a.length); // 1 is printed
```

Now i get the following explanation for 1 being printed;

> Oddly, the length is reported to be 1, yet four keys are printed.
>   That's because we are manipulating both the array elements and the
>   underlying object.

**underlying object** ? excuse me , i did't quite understand , can anybody explain please? what is this underlying object ? can anybody emphasis ? please note that my question is't directly why 1 is printed but rather i am asking a slightly wider and difficult question and that is what is the underlying object ?

Found the example **[HERE](http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html)**

Comment: length is not the number of elements in an array, it's the value of the highest non-negative integer key+1. arrays are objects. the underlying object refers to non expando (integer) keys which are not included in length. generally, you should put alphabetic properties on a object ({}), not an array ([]), even if javascript lets you tack properties onto about anything, including functions, RegExps, Dates, etc...

Comment: @dandavis superb thanks !

Comment: and the `a.push(77);` would make it 2 length with value 77 because your [0] gives it 1 length prior and [13] with a push would have made it 15 length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `length` property of an array is simply the next integer after the biggest integer index in the array.

For example, if you declare the following array:

```
var arr = [];
arr[1234] = 'Hello world';
```

Then, `arr.length` will be equal to 1235.

Adding any object properties to it won't affect it:

```
arr['one'] = '1';
arr['two'] = '2';
arr['three'] = '3';

console.log(arr.length); // still 1235
```

Moreover, it is correct to not assign such properties to an array.

It is also important to mention that if you decide to `JSON.stringify` this array now, you will get:

```
[null, null, null, null, ... 1250 more nulls ..., "Hello world"]
```

without `one`, `two`, `three` etc.